# How do I attach my variable to my class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

So I have been stuck on this for some time now, and cant seem to get the right syntax.

I have a While loop which goes through several elements successfully until it reaches some forms.

I'm attempting to make each form with in the while loop to have a different(unique) class id, at the moment i'm just using a simple count which is attached to the onclick and also class.

The onclick then runs the JS, I'm just struggling to add the unique count to the class in the JS, hopefully my code will explain more.

**JS**

```
function hidelike(t) {
if ($(".like").is(':visible')) {

    $(".like").hide();
    $(".unlike").show();
    $(".dislike").hide();


} else {
   $(".like").show();
   $(".unlike").hide();
   $(".dislike").show();
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="likesubmit<?php echo $like_count;?>">
<input type="button" class="like<?php echo $like_count;?>" value="Like"  onclick="hidelike(<?php echo $like_count;?>)">   
</form>
```

I have defined the count already so that's not the problem I have also alerted the count in the JS and that works fine.

Hope I explained my problem okay, thanks in advance James.

Comment: `class="like<?php echo $like_count;?>"` it would produce classes `like15` `like2345` etc, so `$('.like')` will return nothing.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I'm trying the add the php var on to the $('.like')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as far as I see from your HTML you have no element with a class of like.
if you want to target all classes of the form `like1`, `like2` ... , you want to select with:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
if ($('input[class^="like"]').is(':visible')) {
```

or by value

```
if ($('input[value="Like"]').is(':visible')) {
```

Both of the above 2 methods are non-ideal
What you really want to do is add an extra unique class to the inputs you want to target.

in your PHP this time:

```
<form class="likesubmit<?php echo $like_count;?>">
<input type="button" class="like like<?php echo $like_count;?>" value="Like"  onclick="hidelike(<?php echo $like_count;?>)">   
</form>
```

Notice the `class="like like<?php ...."`. This way, your inputs will have 2 classes:

- a normal `like` class
- and a unique `like1`, `like2` ... etc class

So if you just use your current JS it will work

UPDATE: your JS is wrong. You are selecting ALL like, dislike, etc buttons when you click *any* button

what you need is:

**PHP** (add an extra number attribute to all buttons (also to the dislike, etc))

```
<form class="likesubmit<?php echo $like_count;?>">
<input type="button" class="like like<?php echo $like_count;?>" number="<?php echo $like_count; ?>" value="Like"  onclick="hidelike(<?php echo $like_count;?>)">   
</form>
```

**JS** (use the number attribute)

```
function hidelike(t) {
if ($(".like" + t).is(':visible')) {
    $(".like" + t).hide();
    $(".unlike" + t).show();
    $(".dislike" + t).hide();
} else {
   $(".like" + t).show();
   $(".unlike" + t).hide();
   $(".dislike" + t).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Its still affecting each instance of the button. For example I have 6 entries in my database and the loop is looping through 6 times, when I click one of the buttons in one of the loops it changes them all.

Comment: your JS was wrong: you were selecting ALL buttons all the time

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, however it's not doing anything now aslo what do you mean by.."assuming t is the input[type=button] with the number attribute"

Comment: how do you call hidelike? what is the object you pass to hidelike? is it the input or what is it?

Comment: Oh I see I call it with the onclick with the count"onclick="hidelike(<?php echo $like_count;?>)"

Comment: ah didn't see that in your code. then you just need `number = t` check my update

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `data` attribute here.

```
<input class="like" data-id="<?= $like_count?>" onclick="hidelike(this)" />
```

Then you can extract the property if you really need it or just hide the element.

```
function hideLike(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var id = $elem.data('id');

    $elem.hide();
    $('input.like[data-id='+id+']').hide();
}
```